# How to export user's content via features to new site in Drupal 7

Tags: media, users, features

Can anyone tell me how to export contents of users through some contributed modules?? like features,because I have a site which has 100 users,all contents are migrating through features but user's info and their images are not being moved with features module..

Your solicited help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data export import module
Here ls the link of module - https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import

Comment: is it dump all users info to a file format?? because i would need to migrate my users details to another fresh installed drupal website of a different hosted domain...

Comment: yes..you can import it on fresh installed drupal site

Comment: In your fresh website,download data_export_import module and then import users data

Comment: if i don't want to import from dumped user file to new fresh Drupal site,is it possible with features or feature_uuid kind of modules where it automatically do that job on creating my features of old site??